# Refresh Form1 after closing Form2

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want to refresh my datagrid in Form1 after I updated the database in Form2. My Problem is that it isn't updating the datagrid in Form1 after i close Form2. Literally I am not sure how to do that. Can someone help me please?

This is how i create my datagrid (in Form1):

```
LagerDBEntities1 dataEntities = new LagerDBEntities1();          
var query =
   from product in dataEntities.Artikel
   select new { product.Id, product.artikelname, product.bestand };            
   dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

This is how i switch to Form2:

```
Window2 Auslagern = new Window2(currbestand, artikelid, artikelname);
this.Close();
Auslagern.Show();
```

This is how i switch to Form1:

```
MainWindow Main = new MainWindow();
this.Close();
Main.Show();
```

In Form2 I am updating the database:

```
int counter = currentbestand - ValueS;
if (counter > 0)
    {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"X");
            try
            {

                con.Open();
                string Query = "update Artikel set bestand='" + counter + "' where id='" + artikelid + "' ";
                SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
                createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            MainWindow Main = new MainWindow();
            this.Close();
            Main.Show();


        }
```

So how can I switch back to Form1 and see the updated datagrid?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would look into `RelayCommands` and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `ViewModels` and datagrid collection

Comment: You're not switching between the forms - you're creating new ones each time. Are you wanting to simply switch or are you after the current behaviour you've got?

Comment: I just want to switch between Forms and then update the datagrid in Form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - problem solved!

This wasn't working properly:

```
LagerDBEntities1 dataEntities = new LagerDBEntities1();          
var query =
   from product in dataEntities.Artikel
   select new { product.Id, product.artikelname, product.bestand };            
   dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

So i replaced it with this and it worked:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=X");
        SqlDataAdapter Query = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT Id, artikelname, bestand FROM Artikel", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        Query.Fill(dt);

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Thanks to Binuriki Cliean Jay.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Form2 adds its information to the database, you could put your code that fills the Datagrid into a public method and then call it each time you load the form, because it looks like you create a new instance of Form1 after closing Form2.

```
public void LoadDatagrid()
{
    LagerDBEntities1 dataEntities = new LagerDBEntities1();          
    var query =
           from product in dataEntities.Artikel
           select new { product.Id, product.artikelname, product.bestand };            
           dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

and then call `LoadDatagrid` in Form1's Show event

Comment: It didn't work. It's still showing the old datagrid before the update.

Comment: What is happening in Form2? Is it adding information to the database that Datagrid is loaded from? Please provide more code to help us understand the problem.

Comment: I am just updating the database. You can see the code above

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the `Window.Activated()` event for Form 1

Just add the handler in the code for Form 1 and when the window is activated i.e. brought back to focus, the DataGrid is refreshed.

```
public class Form1 : Window {

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    private void RefreshDataGrid() {
        // Refresh DataGrid Here
    }

    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        RefreshDataGrid();
    }
}
```

The only issue with this is that the event will be fired every time the window is activated.

Another way to achieve this is to pass a reference to Form 1 into Form 2 when you call it and trigger a public event in Form 1, from Form 2

```
public class Form1 : Window {

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
    }

    public void RefreshDataGrid() {
        // Refresh DataGrid Here
    }
}

public class Form2 : Window {

    private Form1 Form1Ref;

    public Form2(Form1 f1) {
        Form1Ref = f1;
    }

    void Form2_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        if (Form1Ref != null) Form1Ref.RefreshDataGrid();
    }
}
```

Apologies for any mistakes. Code was written freehand.

Answer (score 0):

in your win 1:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadDatagrid();
}

public void LoadDatagrid()
{
    LagerDBEntities1 dataEntities = new LagerDBEntities1();          
    var query =
           from product in dataEntities.Artikel
           select new { product.Id, product.artikelname, product.bestand };            
           dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

change your codes when switching to win 2 into:

```
Window2 Auslagern = new Window2(currbestand, artikelid, artikelname);
Auslagern.Show();
this.Close();
```

then when you switch back from win 2 to win1:

```
MainWindow Main = new MainWindow();
Main.Show();
this.Close();
```

the `public MainWindow()` will take care of refreshing the datagrid

Comment: It didn't work. it isn't refreshing the Datagrid the MainWindow() is taking care of LoadDatagrid but it isn't refreshing it.

Comment: kinda weird. im pretty sure the " var query =
           from product in dataEntities.Artikel..." should retrieve the latest entries from the table. then will go to the datagridview.itemsource

Comment: in your win 1, try adding a button, then double click it to go to the click event. then put this: LoadDatagrid(); then run it, update the row in win form 2. then check you databasse table if the new row really was inserted or updated. if the database didn't get updated, then, the problem is your insert/update. if not, then go back to main form. then press the button. if the database didnt refresh, then  try putting a break point in LoadDataGrid and see what happens on your query. the query might be wrong

Comment: the insert/update is working but i must close the current program and restart it. When i do this then it shows me the updated datagrid otherwise not..

Comment: I tried it with a button right now but it didn't work and i also checked my database, the row was updated

Comment: probably the var query = from ... isn't working properly

Comment: I have a local database (File) in visual studio how could i do it differently?